# How to prevent from data looping in jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-select2

This is regarding assigning multiple user using `Select2` plugin, Ajax and API. The situation, I have a function that contain of 2 Ajax with different pointed URL. Currently, I have pre-selected user that stored in DB. The selection is using `Select2` in a Modal. So what is happen now when Modal is opened, 1st Ajax will load URL `/all_user` to display all user in DB. After that 2nd Ajax will load URL `/activity` to get and load information for other fields in the same Modal. Both URLs are running in parallel.

URL `/all_user` successful to display all user. URL `/activity` also successful to display pre-selected user. However, when I close the Modal and re-open back the same Modal without refresh page, it will definitely load the same function that contain 2 Ajax as mentioned above.

FYI, in `/activity` I have doing a function to convert from String to Array since I received in String from DB, so need to convert before displaying in `Select`.

So the problem is both are the data will be duplicate 2x, when I close and re-open, it will duplicate 3x. How to prevent from the duplication?

Below are the pre-selected `Select2` in `/activity`.

[image]

Below are the `/all_user` that successfully display all user

[image]

So when Modal is close and re-open back, duplication happen.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<select type="text" class="form-control mySelect" id="editOwner" name="editOwner" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

**SELECT2 INIT**

```
var mySelect = $('.mySelect').select2({
   allowClear: true,
   placeholder: "Search Owner...",
   minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
   width: 600,
});
```

**JS**

```
<span onclick='editOwner(&quot;"+value3.l3_id+"&quot;)'></span>

function editOwner(id){

    activity_id = id;

    $.ajax ({
        url: '/all_user',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        processData: true,
        data: 'data',
        success: function(response){
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
                $("#editOwner").append($("<option>", {
                    response: response.data[i].fullname,
                    text: response.data[i].fullname
                }));
            }
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url : '/activity',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        processData: true,
        data: {task_id: activity_id}},
        success: function(response){
                if (response.status == "Success"){
                    $("#editOwner").val(response.data[0]["task_owner"]).attr("readonly",false);

                    $(response.data).each(function(key,value){
                        var owners = value.task_owner.split(',');
                        $(owners).each(function(k,v){
                            $("#editOwner").append($("<option selected>", {
                                response: v,
                                text: v
                            }));
                        });
                        $("#editOwner").val(owners).trigger("change");
                    });

                }
                else {}
        },
        error: function(e){}
    });

    $('#editOwnerModal').modal('show');    
}
```

Comment: Why not request the select2 field data once when loading the page instead of every time you open the modal?

Comment: I don't how, can you guide me by give solution in answer section? i am new in js. do you mean put `$(response.data).each(function(key,value){}` outside from function?

Comment: Sure, but it would help if you would include more code. Specifically the parts where you initialize Select2 and where you call the `editOwner` function.

Comment: Well, now you trigger both `$.ajax` functions from within the `editOwner` function. So like you explained, every time you open the modal it will download the data from the server. But if you only need to download it once and not when the modal opens, then you don't have to call it *inside* `editOwner`, but just when you load your page.

Comment: I just update the code

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are calling:

```js
editOwner(id);
```

on the click event of your your span that contains your select with the ID of #editOwner.

Like this:

```js
  <body>
    <select id="cars" style="display: block">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function addCar ()
      {
        $("#cars").append
        (
          $("<option>", { response: "Ford", text: "Ford" })
        );
      }

      $("#cars").on
      (
        "click",
        addCar
      );

    </script>
  </body>
```

Every time you open and close the select element with the ID of #editOwner your appending a new option to the select element. You can easily fix this by adding:

```js
$("#editOwner").unbind();
```

Like this:

```js
  <body>
    <select id="cars" style="display: block">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function addCar ()
      {
        $("#cars").append
        (
          $("<option>", { response: "Ford", text: "Ford" })
        );

        // Add this to remove the onclick events for #cars so it will only run one time.
        $("#cars").unbind();
      }

      $("#cars").on
      (
        "click",
        addCar
      );
    </script>
  </body>
```

Or better yet you could only have the function run one time by not calling it with a onclick event at all like this:

```js
  <body>
    <select id="cars" style="display: block">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function addCar ()
      {
        $("#cars").append
        (
          $("<option>", { response: "Ford", text: "Ford" })
        );
      }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      addCar();
    </script>
  </body>
```

Unless there is a reason you need to call your ajax with a onclick event you really shouldn't, but if you need to you should call $("#editOwner").unbind(); at the end of editOwner(id); like this:

> Edit: Saw that you were calling editOwner(id) with a span that had a onclick event. Just add an ID to that and call $("#mySpan").prop("onclick", null).off("click");

```js
      <span id="#mySpan" onclick='editOwner(&quot;"+value3.l3_id+"&quot;)'></span>

      function editOwner(id){

      activity_id = id;

      $.ajax ({
          url: '/all_user',
          crossDomain: true,
          type: "POST",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          processData: true,
          data: 'data',
          success: function(response){
              for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
                  $("#editOwner").append($("<option>", {
                      response: response.data[i].fullname,
                      text: response.data[i].fullname
                  }));
              }
          }
      });

      $.ajax({
          url : '/activity',
          crossDomain: true,
          type: "POST",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          processData: true,
          data: {task_id: activity_id}},
          success: function(response){
                  if (response.status == "Success"){
                      $("#editOwner").val(response.data[0]["task_owner"]).attr("readonly",false);

                      $(response.data).each(function(key,value){
                          var owners = value.task_owner.split(',');
                          $(owners).each(function(k,v){
                              $("#editOwner").append($("<option selected>", {
                                  response: v,
                                  text: v
                              }));
                          });
                          $("#editOwner").val(owners).trigger("change");
                      });

                  }
                  else {}
          },
          error: function(e){}
      });

      $('#editOwnerModal').modal('show');   

      // Try adding this.
      //$("#editOwner").unbind();

      // Or this if you want to use onclick as an attribute.
      $("#mySpan").prop("onclick", null).off("click");

  }
```